# ggplot2 - highlight specific values

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame of products and time to produce them (days):

```
test <- structure(list(product = c("prod.1", "prod.2", "prod.3", "prod.4", "prod.5",
"prod.6", "prod.7", "prod.8", "prod.9", "prod.10", "prod.11", "prod.12", "prod.13", 
"prod.14", "prod.15", "prod.16", "prod.17", "prod.18", "prod.19", "prod.20", "prod.21", 
"prod.22", "prod.23", "prod.24", "prod.25", "prod.26", "prod.27", "prod.28", "prod.29", 
"prod.30", "prod.31", "prod.32", "prod.33", "prod.34", "prod.35", "prod.36", "prod.37", 
"prod.38", "prod.39", "prod.40", "prod.41", "prod.42", "prod.43", "prod.44", "prod.45", 
"prod.46", "prod.47", "prod.48", "prod.49", "prod.50"), prodTime = c(4.03, 3.8, 3.75, 
3.74, 3.72, 3.7, 3.66, 3.66, 3.66, 3.64, 3.63, 3.63, 3.63, 3.6, 3.6, 3.58, 3.58, 3.58, 
3.57, 3.57, 3.57, 3.56, 3.56, 3.56, 3.56, 3.55, 3.53, 3.53, 3.53, 3.53, 3.53, 3.52, 3.51, 
3.51, 3.51, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.5, 3.49, 3.49, 3.48, 3.48, 3.48, 3.48, 
3.47)), .Names = c("product", "prodTime"), row.names = c(NA, -50L), class = 
c("data.frame"))
```

and have no problem to output a plot which is almost as I would like it:

```
ggplot(data=test, aes(x=prodTime, y=reorder(factor(product), prodTime))) +
  geom_segment(aes(yend=product, xend=0)) + 
  geom_point() + 
  coord_cartesian(xlim=c(2.5, 4.25)) + 
  theme_minimal() + 
  theme(panel.grid.major.y=element_blank(), 
        axis.ticks=element_blank()) + 
  labs(x='', y='') + 
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=3.7), color = 'red', linetype = 'dashed') +
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept=3.3), color = 'blue', linetype = 'dashed')
```

However, what I am trying to get is a similar plot where all product labels (prod.01 to prod.50), segments and points would be very light grey but a couple of them would be highlighted (for instance, in a different color). Say prod.03, prod.12, prod.29, prod.41 to be the only ones (labels, segments and points) to be highlighted.

Any suggestion is most welcomed.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add new column to your data frame where products are divided in two groups (should be highlighted or not).

```
test$high<-ifelse(test$product %in% c("prod.3", "prod.12", "prod.29", "prod.41"),"Yes","No")
```

Then use this new column for `color=` in `aes()` of `ggplot()`. Colors you can change with `scale_color_manual()`.

```
ggplot(data=test,aes(x=prodTime,y=reorder(factor(product),prodTime),color=high)) + 
      geom_segment(aes(yend=product, xend=0)) + geom_point() + 
      coord_cartesian(xlim=c(2.5, 4.25)) + theme_minimal() + 
      theme(panel.grid.major.y=element_blank(), axis.ticks=element_blank()) + 
      labs(x='', y='') + 
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept=3.7), color = 'red', linetype = 'dashed') +
      geom_vline(aes(xintercept=3.3), color = 'blue', linetype = 'dashed')+
      scale_color_manual(values=c("grey50","red"),guide=FALSE)
```

[image]

Comment: easy, actually ! Thank you very much